# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotify'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, spotify

I made a mistake, when i was creating the file to access the spotify api with my application i accidentally created the folder 'spotify' inside my app folder.

Now i tried to move the spotify folder into the django folder, so it would be in the same directory as my app.

The issue is that when i try to migrate it shows: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotify'.

Do you guys have a tip? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It says that the problem is in this function:

```
def update_or_create_user_tokens(session_id, access_token, token_type, expires_in, refresh_token):
    tokens = get_user_tokens(session_id)
    expires_in = timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
```

Comment: use the OS to move the folder by GUI or by shell command

Comment: Still getting the sane error...

Comment: did you add the path in your settings.py?

Comment: it should tell you where, which file and line, it tries to import `spotify`

Comment: Just added that in the question, thanks!